# USB Voltage step down over Cat5e extender

Tags: voltage-regulator

Using a USB voltage extender via cat5e to power a web camera. This works fine when the camera is run on 5v. However, the camera I need to use runs at 3.3v. I cannot fine a strait USB to USB step down converter (as in a USB plug on both ends).

Viewing my very crude photoshop image, will this do the trick?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The extender is irrelevant. Basically your question is, how do you power 3.3V items from USB. That has been asked before, also regarding such cameras removed from laptops.

Comment: I understand the converter drops the 5v to 3.3v to power the camera. My question is how do I make the data lines work? Do I just bypass the converter and go directly to the camera?